# SSL/TLS Mutual Authentication not working

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm trying to enable mutual authentication between Outlook and my Dovecot IMAPS server. I have traffic working over SSL/TLS currently but want to use the mutual auth with client certificates as an additional means of authentication.

In Dovecot I have the following options turned enabled:

```
ssl_ca = ...
ssl_verify_client_cert = yes
auth_ssl_require_client_cert = yes
auth_ssl_username_from_cert = yes
```

When I connect with openssl directly and send a client certificate the log says that it works. But when I turn on Outlook and try to connect it fails to authenticate with Dovecot saying:

```
Disconnected (client didn't send a cert): user=<>, method=PLAIN ...
```

The client certificate is installed on my Windows 10 machine in my user's personal certificate store and it has the "Client Authentication" x509 extension on it.

Is there a way to tell Outlook to send the client certificate?

Comment: AFAIK, Outlook does not support the ability to select a Client Certificate at this time

Comment: So I figured that I didn't have to tell it which certificate to use... I figured that I had to say "Look in the trust stores for a certificate that is signed by the CA's the server wants" Can it at least do that? Or are you saying it can not do mutual auth for IMAP at all?

Comment: Here is what I found: Outlook will establish an SSL/TLS connection and verify the server’s certificate, but unfortunately does not provide the ability to select a client certificate to give the server for Auth with SSL/TLS. Reference:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/59850cac-bcc8-4ad6-b1aa-f1c337ba2c5c/how-to-use-client-certificate-to-authenticate-outlook-to-smtp-server?forum=outlook

Comment: Wow! That is such an old document. I was really hoping that things would have changed since then. Guess not. Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm afraid not. There would be an announcement from Microsoft if things have been changed, but I haven't found anything related on this.